# getting cannot create VM error from JVM

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

I have a C program which calls JNI.
In this we create JVM.

I am getting following error -

Can not create VM

This is not a regular error. Something this error goes away and starts coming again.

This error comes after calling routine - JNI_CreateJavaVM

Can anyone please suggest what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error occur when the JVM heap initial size is more than the amount of available memory.

For example, on a machine with 4 GB of RAM, you pass in a -ms3000m for a 3 GB heap.  Though technically possible, that is probably going to fail given everything else running on your machine.

Comment: we are passing Xms64m -Xmx64m and by doing TOP i see around 814MB available. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but I know the JVM will allocate quite a bit more for its own use.  But I'd be surprised if it was THAT much more.